# How can I detect if the current post is in this loop?

Tags: wp-query, featured-post

My featured articles have been built with the following query:

```
$featured_posts = new WP_Query(  array(  'post__not_in' =--> get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
 'meta_key' => is_featured',
 'meta_value' => 1
 ) );
```

How can I detect if my current (singlepage) article is featured or not? I obviously need to query whether it has `is_featured` flag, but how do I build this query?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$is_featured_post = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'is_featured', TRUE);`

This will return the value in the variable and you can check your condition.

Instead of `get_the_ID()`, you can use any post `ID`. Refer the documentation here: [get_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta).